# How to make a table with very little text stretch over the entire screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple table with two columns and I want that table to stretch over the entire width of the page irrespective of the contents it contains (it hardly contains any text, that's the problem):

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is: This doesn't work in Firefox (I didn't even dare to try Internet Explorer yet).

This is the CSS:

```
div {
  max-width: 640px;
  float: left;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table th,
table td {
  width: 100%; /* looks strange, but gives both columns equal length in Safari */
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

Make your `th` and `td` 50% wide, not 100% - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Eed4x/)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

table th, table td {   
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I commented TheAlbear's answer above. Maybe I didn't provide enough info in my first question. Hope it's better now :-)

Comment: @Tintin81 you want to stretch your table besides its parent width?

Comment: No, ideally the table should stretch over the exact width of the parent div.

Comment: You are right! The problem is that I need to `float` the div though. I added one more line to my initial question. I think the float is causing the problem... http://jsfiddle.net/Eed4x/11/

Comment: yeap, the float causing it.. if you change it to `inline-block` (which is essentially the same) then - http://jsfiddle.net/Eed4x/12/

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Wow, this is getting tricky. The problem is that I **must** float the containing div though. Any idea on that one?

Comment: if you float the div you have to give it some width - http://jsfiddle.net/Eed4x/15/  In order to change its width to something else ( i.e. 100% for screens less than 600px ) you can use media queries

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. I am just trying to avoid media queries in this project in order to keep everything as simple as possible. I wonder if this is possible in this case?

Answer (score 1):

just change the css to

```
table th,
table td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

The issue you have at the moment is that each cell in the table is trying to be 100% the width of the table.

[See for example](http://jsfiddle.net/BC9tX/)

Comment: OK, of course you are right. This was the first thing I tried. The problem seems to be the containing `div` though which has a `max-width` to make it responsive. I've just updated my initial question. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `td` to 50% from 100% is true, but you should also add `border-collapse` to your table, since you're using borders on your cells.

`width:80%` works fine too -- no need for an explicit px width (at least not in FF, Chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/UdbRQ/

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact I am using `border-collapse` in my code. I just wanted to keep my initial post short, so I omitted it.